# Having problems with Jquery slider on when the left arrow is pressed

Tags: jquery, slider

I'm having trouble making a slider, it works fine when you press the right hand arrow but when I go to press the left hand button it completely messes up the script.

I was wondering if anyone could look at my code and see if there is anything obviously wrong with it. As I've taken the code from a different site that it works with no problems on.

I have a link here:

http://emopreview.co.uk/STIHL/12113081/video.html

And the Jquery is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var nav = $('#wrapper .slider').css('overflow', 'hidden').children('ul'),
sliding = false,
ul = $('#wrapper .slider ul'),
count = $('#wrapper .slider ul li').length,
width = count * 178;    

$('#wrapper .slider ul').width(width);

    function slideLeft() {
        if(sliding){
            return false;
        }
        sliding = true;
        ul.animate({
            left: '0'
        }, 1000, function(){
            sliding = false;
        });
    }
    function moveLeft() {
        $('#wrapper .slider ul li:first').insertBefore($('#wrapper .slider ul li:last'));
        ul.css("left", "-178px");
    }

    function slideRight() {
        if(sliding){
            return false;
        }
        sliding = true;
        ul.animate({
            left: '-=178'
        }, 1000, function() {
            sliding = false;

            $('#wrapper .slider ul li:first').appendTo(ul);
            ul.css("left", "0");
        });
    }
    var autoSlide;
    autoSlide = setInterval(function() {
        slideRight();
    }, 3000);

    $('#wrapper .slider_container').mouseenter(function() {
        clearInterval(autoSlide);
    }).mouseleave(function() {
        autoSlide = setInterval(function() {
            slideRight();
        }, 3000);
    });
    $('#slider-nav').show();

    $('#slider-nav .right_arrow').click(slideRight);

    $('#slider-nav .left_arrow').click(function() {
        moveLeft();
        slideLeft();
    });
 });
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code like this :

```
    function slideLeft() {
        if(sliding){
            return false;
        }
        sliding = true;
        ul.animate({
            left: ''
        }, 1000, function(){
            sliding = false;
            ul.css("left","0px");
        });
    }
    function moveLeft() {
        ul.css("left", "-178px");           
        $('#wrapper .slider ul li:last').insertBefore($('#wrapper .slider ul li:first'));
    }
```

**Two issues** :

- You moved your first `li` to the end of the `ul`, even if you intended to move leftward.
- Your animation and absolute positioning were wrong.